# Geolocation in Azure

Tags: azure, google-geolocation

I want to get end user latitude and longitude using google API on page load (without any inputs). Sample code using "navigator.gelocation" is not working in azure.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the following sample code "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp ".  It works in localhost. But not in Azure VM.

Comment: Are you accessing it from your machine or via Remote Desktop/SSH? Do you get an error?

Comment: I am accessing it from my machine only and also no remote desktop/SSH. No I am not getting error.

Comment: There really should be nothing different with a script hosted in a VM vs hosting it in localhost. Origin is different of course.

Comment: So what is the issue. May I know?